# How to work with Eigen Sparse Matrix in a GPU kernel

Tags: c++, cuda, eigen

I'm a beginner with Eigen and CUDA.
I'm trying to work in CUDA with Eigen Sparse Matrix, in particular I want to pass to the kernel the pointer pointing to values not equal to 0.
The code works but the output is not correct. It should be something like

```
0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3
0   0   0
```

but I obtain something like:

```
0.3 0.3 0.3 0 0 4.94066e-324 0 
0.3 0.3 1.63042e-322 
0 0 0
```

My second question is: how can I copy into the kernel only values different from 0 ?
This is the code:

```
 #include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
#include <Eigen/Core>

const int BLOCK_DIM = 8; 


__global__ void cu_fun(double *input, double *out, int N){
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(idx < N){
        out[idx] = input[idx]/10;
    }
}

int main(){   

int n = 3; 
int nrow = n;
int ncol = n;
Eigen::SparseMatrix <double> spMat(n,n); 
Eigen::SparseMatrix <double> out(n,n); 


for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
        spMat.insert(i,j) = 3;
    }
}  

const int non0 = spMat.nonZeros(); 
std::vector <double> value(non0);
double *dev_in = new double[non0];
double *dev_ret = new double[non0]; 


cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_in, sizeof(double)*non0);
cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_ret, sizeof(double)*non0);

cudaMemcpy(dev_in, spMat.valuePtr(), sizeof(double) * non0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


cu_fun<<< 8,1>>>(dev_in, dev_ret, non0);


cudaMemcpy(value.data(), dev_ret, sizeof(double) * non0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> mat_map(nrow, ncol, non0, spMat.outerIndexPtr(), spMat.innerIndexPtr(), value.data());

out = mat_map.eval();

std::cout << spMat
          << "\n"
<< out;
}
```

Comment: This plainly isn't the code you are running, what you have posted won't even compile. If you want help, please post a useful repro case

Comment: I uploaded the working code and I reformulated the question. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the Eigen [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#a9dc538b2c1fe9027ba58f31ee83b2ff1) for `Eigen::SparseMatrix`

> Unlike the compressed format, there might be extra space inbetween the nonzeros of two successive colmuns (resp. rows) such that insertion of new non-zero can be done with limited memory reallocation and copies.

Your code assumes that all the non zero entries  in `spMat` will lie in the range `spMat.valuePtr()` to `spMat.valuePtr()+spMat.nonZeros()`. That will only be the case if the matrix is compressed. Your matrix is not compressed. If you add a call to `spMat.makeCompressed()` after value assignment, you should find the code will work correctly. Modifying the array construction and non-zero copying to this:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix <double> spMat(n,n);
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
        spMat.insert(i,j) = 3;
    }
}

spMat.makeCompressed();
const int non0 = spMat.nonZeros();
std::vector <double> value(non0);
double *dev_in; cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_in, sizeof(double)*non0);
double *dev_ret; cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_ret, sizeof(double)*non0);
cudaMemcpy(dev_in, spMat.valuePtr(), sizeof(double) * non0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

[Note the `new` calls you included and assigned to `dev_in` and `dev_out` are superfluous and serve only to leak memory]

gets me this:

```
$  nvcc -arch=sm_53 -std=c++11 -o eigennono -I $EIGENPATH eigennono.cu
$ ./eigennono
Nonzero entries:
(3,0) (3,1) (3,0) (3,1) (3,0) (3,1)

Outer pointers:
0 2 4  $

3 3 3
3 3 3
0 0 0

Nonzero entries:
(0.3,0) (0.3,1) (0.3,0) (0.3,1) (0.3,0) (0.3,1)

Outer pointers:
0 2 4  $

0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3
0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Using makeCompressed() everything works!

Comment: I have also another doubt, the code works but when I tried with a sparse matrix greater than 250x250 the output is a zero matrix! Is this due to the memory bounds of the GPU? Do you know a solution? The number of blocks I used is non0/BLOCK_DIM  and BLOCK_DIM is 64. Thanks! @talonmies